# pushing notification for distribution not working

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

after i've published before ( 48 hours ) my 1st iOS app in the app store i was shocked that after all the tries i've tried in the developing version of pushing notification was always fine , but now it is not working in the production one !!!!

in spite of that  parse.com is showing me number of subscribers , they are raising but not receiving the notification after i send it

the distribution certificate is correct and every thing is fine but i don't know what is the problem??

```
can any body help ?
```

Comment: If you assume that everything is corrent with the certificate you should consider the server issue... Apple doesn't guarantee that notification will always be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

For live apps, you have to use the distribution certificate as explained in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html).

create and Upload your certificate(.p12) on parse and probably resubmit the app by regenerating the provisioning profile and archiving with it.

Comment: i already used the distribution p12 certificate

but do u mean that i have to update my app ?

Comment: try adhoc testing first then. sign your app with adhoc provisioning profile. create build and sync to your device. then send push to your device. test in both ways. App in foreground and in background

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to resubmit the app. You will need to create a new key using the production certificates.

it's called `aps_production.cer`

Comment: you mean that i download the certificate from developer.apple.com of production certificate ? , but parse needs .p12 certificate , please if u can help me i'll appreciate that from u

Comment: yes you would export the .p12 from that certificate, just like you did with the development one

Comment: i did that really and as i said that i can see the number of recipient , it is showing that it is active but i am not receiving any notification neither other devices

Comment: @Omalibr are you available for [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50313/pushnotifications) ?

Comment: man this chat is bad , i still can't chat , this is my email  omalibr@gmail.com , do u have gmail ? so we can talk

Comment: @Omalibr I sent you invite